# How to update matrix-like-data (.txt) file in bash programming?

Tags: bash, programming-languages

I am new to bash programming. I have this file, the file contain is:

```
   A B C D E
 1 X 0 X 0 0
 2 0 X X 0 0
 3 0 0 0 0 0
 4 X X X X X
```

Where X means, it has value, 0 means its empty.

From there, let say user enter B3, which is a 0, means I will need to replace it to X. What is the best way to do it? I need to constantly update this file.

FYI: This is a homework question, thus please, dont give a direct code/answer. But any sample code like (how to use this function etc) will be very much appreciated).

Regards,

Newbie Bash Scripter

EDIT:

If I am not wrong, Bash can call/update directly the specific column. Can it be done with row+column?

Comment: I think you need to reformat your input data

Comment: SiegeX, what do you mean? Means, instead of rows+columns, I should change it to rows only?

Comment: Does this have to be straight Bash or can you call external programs like sed or awk?

Answer (score 1):

If you can use `sed` I'll throw out this tidbit:

```
sed -i "/^2/s/. /X /4" /path/to/matrix_file
```

#### Input

```
  A B C D E
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 X 0 0 X 0
3 X X 0 0 X
```

#### Output

```
  A B C D E
1 0 0 0 0 0
2 X 0 X X 0
3 X X 0 0 X
```

#### Explanation

`^2`: This restricts sed to only work on lines which begin with `2`, i.e. the 2nd row

`s`: This is the replacement command

*Note* for the next two, '_' represents a white space

`._`: This is the pattern to match. The `.` is a regular expression that matches any character, thus `._` matches "any character followed by a space".  Note that this could also be `[0X]_` if you are guaranteed that the only two characters you can have are '0' and 'X'

`X_`: This is the replacement text. In this case we are replacing 'any character followed by a space' as described above with 'X followed by a space'

`4`: This matches the 4th occurrence of the pattern text above, i.e. the 4th row *including* the row index.

What would be left for you to do is use variables in the place of `^2` and `4` such as `^$row` and `$col` and then map the letters A - E to 1 - 5

Answer (score -1):

something to get you started

```
#!/bin/bash
# call it using ./script B 1
# make it executable using "chmod 755 script"

# read input parameters

col=$1
row=$2

# construct below splits on whitespace
while read -a line
do
    for i in ${line[@]}; do
        array=( "${array[@]}" $i );
    done
done < m

# Now you have the matrix in a one-dimensional array that can be indexed.

# Lets print it

for i in ${array[@]}; do
    echo $i;
done
```

Comment: You can also do `array+=($i)`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a starter for you using AWK:

```
awk -v col=B -v row=3 'BEGIN{getline; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) cols[$i]=i+1} NR==row+1{print $cols[col]}'
```

The `i+1` and `row+1` account for the row heading and column heading, respectively.