# Display data in matrix format?

Tags: bash

I have this file, data.txt, the content is:

```
100X00
20X0X0
3000XX
4X00XX
```

I want to display in matrix format like

```
    A    B    C    D    E
1             X         
2        X         X     
3                  X    X
4   X              X    X
```

I am free to use any command, like sed/awk or grep. My current method is:

```
a=0
echo -e "\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE"
while read line
    do a=$(($a+1));
    sed '{s/0/ /g}' data.txt
done < data.txt
```

Of course its not working. Anyone can help me on this?

Comment: Ok, I'm either going to ask or burst. This wouldn't by any chance be related to a homework assignment that has something to do with airplane seats and booking? In the last few days I have seen at least two other questions regarding bash and processing files in that format...

Comment: hmmm, you're right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4262708/bash-automatic-update-data-file-and-display

Comment: @ltn100: also this one seems eerily similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255294/how-to-update-matrix-like-data-txt-file-in-bash-programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo -e "\tA\tB\tC\tD\tE"
sed 's|.|&\t|g; s|\t0|\t|g; s|\t*$||' <data.txt
```

This seems to work fine with the input sample you provided.

EDIT:

Explanation:

Add a horizontal tab (\t) after each character, then remove those zeros that are prepended by a tab (and thus are not in the first column), then remove any tabs from the end of the line.

EDIT2:

Please note that there is a slight change in comparison to my very first answer. I will leave its effects as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: You are genius. If you could explain the sed code, it would be much better for new bash script learner like me. Could you please?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. After play with it, I think I understand the code now. But I am abit sad, when you say I am posting a homework in my other post =(

Comment: The redirection is unnecessary `sed` accepts a filename as an argument.